# Adding menu in bitrix24

Tags: php, bitrix

I want to add menu in bitrix24 which is open in new tab.

```
$arMenuB24[] = array(
        "google",
        "www.google.com",
        array("target"=>"_blank"),
        array(
            "menu_item_id" => "menu_google",
            "my_tools_section" => true,
            "target"=>"_blank"
            //"hidden" => true
        )

    );
```

I want to open google link in new tab.Please suggest how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to:

**1) use escaped characters** like below:

```
$arMenuB24[] = array(
        "google",
        "https:\\www.google.com\" target=\"_blank", 
        ...
    );
```

**2) Modify menu template** to utilize your custom params